# Paste values together based on a grouping variable

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm new at R programing and Im trying to rearrange a data frame.  Basically I have a column with IDs and a column with y string values.  There's more than one y per ID so multiple rows with the same ID but different y. I want to get only one row per ID and all the y value concatenated in the same cell in the other column.  Is there a function that does that ?

```
original data

ID  y
A   apple
B   pear
C   grape
A   grape
B   apple
C   grape

transformed data  

ID   y  
A    apple,grape  
B    pear, apple  
C    grape
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `aggregate()` here to `paste()` the `unique()` elements for each `ID`together

```
aggregate(y ~ ID, unique(dat), paste, collapse = ", ")
```

**data**

```
dat <- read.table(text="ID  y
A   apple
B   pear
C   grape
A   grape
B   apple
C   grape", header=T)
```

**EDIT** added `collapse` argument re @pdb comment and changed `unique` re @DavidArenburg

Comment: If you want to be able to use the results you probably want a single value for each level.

agg2 <- aggregate(y ~ ID, data=dat, function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse=", "))

Comment: I think you can skip running `unique` in each aggregation and just do `aggregate(y ~ ID, unique(dat), paste, collapse = ", ")` both for efficiency and simplicity.

Comment: yes , quite right @DavidArenburg. I forget that unique has a dataframe method. (PS always feel free to improve my answers)